# How to get the Inner Element value from Elements in xml linq

Tags: xml, linq

How to get the Elements, inner Element value in string value.

My XML format is,

```
 <Filters>
   <filterValues>
      <filter_id>BN</filter_id>
      <value>100</value>
   </filterValues>
   <filterValues>
      <filter_id>SRE</filter_id>
      <value>355</value>
   </filterValues>
 </Filters>
```

In this xml, I want to get the Value field based on the `filter_id` Property.
  So that, I have written a query.

```
  var searchp = 
      from t1 in doc.Elements("filters")
      where (string)(t1.Elements("filterValues").Elements().Select(elem=>elem.Element("filter_id").Value).ToString()) == "SRE" 
      select new
      {
         valuestr=t1.Element("filterValues").Element("value").Value                   
      };
```

Pls Help Me.

Answer (score 2):

```
var sr = new StringReader(@"<Filters>
                                   <filterValues>
                                      <filter_id>BN</filter_id>
                                      <value>100</value>
                                   </filterValues>
                                   <filterValues>
                                      <filter_id>SRE</filter_id>
                                      <value>355</value>
                                   </filterValues>
                                 </Filters>");

XElement filters = XElement.Load(sr);
string filterId = "SRE";
var values = filters.Elements().Where(f => f.Element("filter_id").Value == filterId).Select(element => element.Element("value").Value);
foreach (var value in values)
{
    MessageBox.Show(value);
}
```

Comment: Your reply was well. But I have more inner elements in filter values. I need to get all the inner elements. how to get that. Pls Help me. Sorry for the later explation.

Comment: @user1120998 What do those inner elements look like? Update your question with a sample XML and I will help you.

Comment: @user1120998 please update the question with the data example you want to receive to be able to help you

Comment: i got output. Thanks for your time spent for me.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to use xpath to find your node(s). You could use [`XPathSelectElements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176.aspx) entension method for this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var nodes = doc.XPathSelectElements("/Filters/filterValues/filter_id[text()='SRE']/following-sibling::value");
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    // here you can use explicit conversion like
    // var value = (int)node;         if you want to cast the node value to int
    // var node = (string)node;       or to string 
}
```

Comment: what dll to be added for the use of XpathSelectElements. In System.xml.linq doest not contain this method

Comment: @user1120998: this is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). You should add `using System.Xml.XPath;` to your using directives.